# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

What's the best and easiest way to decorate **RecyclerView** to have such look & feel?
i am developing an travels seat booking application...
i know i can do it with **recyclerview with gridlayout manager**..but what should be the steps i dont know 
one thing to be note **each bus have different seating arrangemen**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you to use `StaggeredGridLayoutmanager` for your recycler view.

[image: StaggeredGridLayout for RecyclerView]

It's the closest approach to achieve your layout.

You can find the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html).
And working example can be found [here](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/).

Comment: how you do this layout ....can you post some sample code

Comment: @AawazGyawali: Good one !!

Comment: Can you tell me the steps which i should use....please mail me bro at rajtufan@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

You can learn from this example which explain perfect about [Recycler View](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html)

[image]

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

Based on the type of bus choice, switch between `GridLayoutManager`, and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`.

For all the types, use a header view with just a steering wheel icon right aligned.

1. For the seater-only type:

   - use a 4 span `GridLayoutManager`
   - use an item decorator for providing the spacing between the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> column
   - use a footer view with 5 seats view
2. For the mixed-type:

   - use a 3 span `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`
   - use an item decorator for providing the spacing between the 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> column.
   - use different item type for the sleeper seats (see: [onCreateViewHolder(parent,viewType)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder%28android.view.ViewGroup%2C%20int%29))
3. For the sleeper-only type.

   - use a 4 span `GridLayoutManager`
   - use an item decorator for providing the spacing between the 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> column

Comment: Do you have some sample or anything else..i am not able to find anything like it...

Comment: @tufan, first lesson on SO: don't ask for code.

Comment: okay ...but can you tell me in your 3rd step use an item decorator for providing the spacing between the 1st and 2nd column..how to do it

Comment: The answer here is enough to help you out with your layout. If you don't understand what the answer is taking about, then you'd better learn more about RecyclerView. There are a lot of tutorials out there.

Comment: @Tufan Google for "item decorator in RecyclerView"

Comment: okay thank you i am searching for it....i had lost my hope now i have a seen a light ...i m trying thanks